# How to set header values in Restkit

Tags: ios, restkit

I am trying to set the header values for my restkit calls. However, these do not seem to work.

I want to set `Content-Type` and `Accept` headers to `application/json`

Any idea where the problem is?

Thanks!

```
RKObjectManager *objectManager = [RKObjectManager sharedManager];
[[objectManager client] setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[[objectManager client] setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

RKURL *URL = [RKURL URLWithBaseURL:[objectManager baseURL] resourcePath:@"/users/sign_in.json" queryParameters:params];

[objectManager loadObjectsAtResourcePath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?%@", [URL resourcePath], [URL query]] delegate:self];
```

Answer (score 9):

I don't think it's too obvious, though it is in the [documentation](http://restkit.org/api/master/Classes/RKObjectManager.html#//api/name/serializationMIMEType) (and I haven't tried tbh) but on the object manager there is a `serializationMIMEType` property.  There's also a constant for JSON already defined, so your code would probably look like:

```
objectManager.serializationMIMEType = RKMIMETypeJSON;
```

According to the docs, application/json is the default for Accept anyway, but can be specified by the `acceptMIMEType` property.

Comment: just to be mention: this is only for Accept, not Content-Type

Answer (score 3):

You have this option

```
[kGlobalObjectManager() loadObjectsAtResourcePath: @"path" usingBlock: ^(RKObjectLoader *loader) {
    NSDictionary* dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject: @"VALUE" forKey: @"HEADER NAME"];
    loader.additionalHTTPHeaders = dictionary;
    loader.delegate = self;
}];
```

Of more specific to your problem you have `[RKObjectManager setAcceptMIMEType:]`

Answer (score 0):

In class RKObjectManager exists method

```
**
 This method is the `RKObjectManager` analog for the method of the same name on `AFHTTPClient`.
 */
- (NSMutableURLRequest *)requestWithMethod:(NSString *)method
                                      path:(NSString *)path
                                parameters:(NSDictionary *)parameters
{
    NSMutableURLRequest* request;
    if (parameters && !([method isEqualToString:@"GET"] || [method isEqualToString:@"HEAD"] || [method isEqualToString:@"DELETE"])) {
        // NOTE: If the HTTP client has been subclasses, then the developer may be trying to perform signing on the request
        NSDictionary *parametersForClient = [self.HTTPClient isMemberOfClass:[AFHTTPClient class]] ? nil : parameters;
        request = [self.HTTPClient requestWithMethod:method path:path parameters:parametersForClient];

        NSError *error = nil;
        NSString *charset = (__bridge NSString *)CFStringConvertEncodingToIANACharSetName(CFStringConvertNSStringEncodingToEncoding(self.HTTPClient.stringEncoding));
        [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@; charset=%@", self.requestSerializationMIMEType, charset] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        NSData *requestBody = [RKMIMETypeSerialization dataFromObject:parameters MIMEType:self.requestSerializationMIMEType error:&error];
        [request setHTTPBody:requestBody];
    } else {
        request = [self.HTTPClient requestWithMethod:method path:path parameters:parameters];
    }

    return request;
}
```

Here exists replacement for content-type which you can set early when configure RestKit

```
[[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] HTTPClient] setDefaultHeader:@"Content-Type" value:@"application/json"];
```

For this will work i found (not pretty, but works) solution, i made category

```
@interface RKObjectManager (BBContentType)

- (NSMutableURLRequest *)requestWithMethod:(NSString *)method
                                      path:(NSString *)path
                                parameters:(NSDictionary *)parameters;

@end

@implementation RKObjectManager (BBContentType)

- (NSMutableURLRequest *)requestWithMethod:(NSString *)method
                                      path:(NSString *)path
                                parameters:(NSDictionary *)parameters
{
    NSMutableURLRequest* request;
    if (parameters && !([method isEqualToString:@"GET"] || [method isEqualToString:@"HEAD"] || [method isEqualToString:@"DELETE"])) {
        // NOTE: If the HTTP client has been subclasses, then the developer may be trying to perform signing on the request
        NSDictionary *parametersForClient = [self.HTTPClient isMemberOfClass:[AFHTTPClient class]] ? nil : parameters;
        request = [self.HTTPClient requestWithMethod:method path:path parameters:parametersForClient];
        NSError *error = nil;
        NSData *requestBody = [RKMIMETypeSerialization dataFromObject:parameters MIMEType:self.requestSerializationMIMEType error:&error];
        [request setHTTPBody:requestBody];
    } else {
        request = [self.HTTPClient requestWithMethod:method path:path parameters:parameters];
    }

    return request;
}
@end
```

I just cut two lines

```
NSString *charset = (__bridge NSString *)CFStringConvertEncodingToIANACharSetName(CFStringConvertNSStringEncodingToEncoding(self.HTTPClient.stringEncoding));
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@; charset=%@", self.requestSerializationMIMEType, charset] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
```